# Does OpenID Connect provide CSRF and XSS protection?

Tags: xss, csrf, openid-connect

I've been reading several articles recently about how storing JWTs in local or session storage is inherently insecure. The mitigation is apparently to implement a "session ID pattern", i.e. create a session ID, which is stored in a signed `HttpOnly` cookie and is also included in the JWT, in which case both can be compared server-side to make sure the token corresponds to the right session.

From my limited understanding of the OpenID Connect spec, it seems like that session pattern is part of the specification (as `state` parameter), so I'm assuming that using a compliant implementation should be enough to protect against CSRF/XSS in this particular context.

Is this a correct assumption? Does OpenID Connect spec include CSRF and XSS protection for JWTs?

Answer (score 1):

The `state` parameter (if used correctly) protects against CSRF *during the authentication / authorization step`, but at no further point. It's mostly relevant in the specific case of tying one existing user account to an external identity provider's account, where - without the state parameter - an attacker could tie a victim's existing account to the *attacker's* external account, and then go to the vulnerable site and use SSO with their external account to log into the victim's account on the vulnerable site.

XSS is entirely outside the scope of OAuth/OIDC.

---

The type of dual-token approach you describe (which can be done lots of ways, such as having the JWT or other token in an httponly cookie and storing a hash of it in local storage to include with every request) can protect against CSRF. In a lot of ways this is similar to the double-cookie submit pattern, done right; rather than using a random cookie / anti-CSRF token value, you use one tied to the user's session (and this can be done statelessly with a JWT). On the other hand, you can also avoid CSRF by just not using cookies (or any other authentication token that is submitted automatically, such as HTTP Basic or Digest auth). Storing a JWT in local storage and submitting it as a Bearer token is perfectly secure against CSRF already.

For XSS, the approach you describe won't prevent it at all, but it will *slightly* limit the impact by preventing the attacker from exfiltrating a useful session token (assuming that the value present in local storage is *not* sufficient to re-create the token in the cookie). The thing is, XSS doesn't require exfiltrating tokens at all; once you have XSS, you can make fully-trusted requests to the server, and read the responses, exactly as though you were the legit web page; this means that the attacker can literally remote-control the victim's session (including acting as a proxy to an attacker's browser, if they want), deputizing all actual interaction with the server to your XSS'ed browser but otherwise being logged in as you, and maintaining this control until you close the tab.

However, there are simpler ways to simultaneously prevent stealing the token with XSS and also prevent CSRF. For example, requiring *any* custom header - even `X-No-CSRF: null` or something with a similar fixed value - is enough to prevent CSRF (absent CORS misconfiguration), as trying to add a header to a cross-site request triggers a CORS preflight which the server should not allow (at least not for any site not fully trusted). Similarly, using any content type (such as application/json) other than the ones that are allowed by HTML forms is another way to force CORS preflights and thus break CSRF (although mind that the server actually *enforces* the content type value, and not merely requires that the body be parseable as e.g. JSON).

Finally, consider focusing on actually making your site secure against XSS, instead of merely trying to blunt its impact. There are lots of frameworks that make it easier to avoid XSS, such as React (it's *possible* to get XSS with such frameworks, but you have to misuse them in what are usually fairly obvious ways, such as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`). You can also use Content Security Policy (CSP) with a nice tight restriction that prevents attackers from injecting code inline or from external sources; it's still not supported in IE but everything else has it, and that's generally going to be ~100% of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Binding a JWT token to a session does not protect from CSRF and XSS attacks. The OpenID Connect specification does not include CSRF and XSS specifications, and it conceptually just cannot include it.

**CSRF**

An attacker tricks a user to click on a button, image or link, that triggers some malicious action like transfer $1000 to some account., where as user is not aware of this action. From the server point of view the request will be absolutely correct. In particular, the session ID from httpOnly cookie will be present and valid, also the JWT token will be present, valid and will refer the valid session ID. Thus the server will execute the request.

To protect from CSRF a request should contain something that only server knows, what attacker doesn't know. There are different techniques (synchronizer token, cookie-to-header token, etc.) In all cases this part of the content is provided by the server itself, not by the 3rd party service that issued JWT token.

**XSS**

XSS leads to generation of DOM and/or Script that causes undesired behaviour. Again, from the server point of view any such request will contain valid session ID and valid JWT token.

The protection from XSS includes filtering of input and, on client side, escaping of response elements that are not expected to be DOM elements. JWT does not help to protect from XSS.

Answer (score 0):

OpenIDConnect spec is describing ONLY the authentication process. To protect this process OpenIDConnect (or more like OAuth2 spec) defines the *state* parameter which is provided in Authorization Request. Client is sending *state* value to Athorization Server (AS) and AS is getting back with response including the same *state* value (nevertheless it is successful or not).

The *state* value prevents the CSRF attack on client app, confirming that value comming from response matches the value sent in initial request. In this case the attacker will not know the *state* value and will not be able to send to client any payload (for example with malicious token).

But as I stated at the beginning, it secures the authentication process only.

XSS is the vulnerability which can lead to CSRF attacks and is more related to how application handles the input (filtering) and output (encoding) data. OpenID Connect is not responsible for mitigating such an attacks.